# Go err: cannot use cur (type *user.User) as type string in argument to f.WriteString

Tags: variables, go

How do I convert data to a `string` type? I need to write down the `data` I need to the file which is either not a variable, **how do I do it**?

Code:

```
package main

import "os"
import "os/user"
import "encoding/json"

func main(){
    f, err := os.OpenFile("test.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    cur, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {

    } else {


        if _, err = f.WriteString(cur); err != nil {
        panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I do not need to use the `cur.Username` field. Only a variable.

Comment: What is cur? How is the `struct` like? What data do you want to store in the file?

Comment: @nicovank  need to use cur, err := user.Current() as a string. Save output cur to file

Comment: import package `fmt` and do `f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", cur))`

Comment: @mkopriva thanks! this is what I needed

Answer (score 7):

[`File.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.WriteString) expects a `string` argument, yet you attempt to pass `cur` to it which is of type [`*user.User`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#User), a pointer to a struct. This is obviously a compile-time error.

`user.User` is a struct with the following definition:

```
type User struct {
        // Uid is the user ID.
        // On POSIX systems, this is a decimal number representing the uid.
        // On Windows, this is a security identifier (SID) in a string format.
        // On Plan 9, this is the contents of /dev/user.
        Uid string
        // Gid is the primary group ID.
        // On POSIX systems, this is a decimal number representing the gid.
        // On Windows, this is a SID in a string format.
        // On Plan 9, this is the contents of /dev/user.
        Gid string
        // Username is the login name.
        Username string
        // Name is the user's real or display name.
        // It might be blank.
        // On POSIX systems, this is the first (or only) entry in the GECOS field
        // list.
        // On Windows, this is the user's display name.
        // On Plan 9, this is the contents of /dev/user.
        Name string
        // HomeDir is the path to the user's home directory (if they have one).
        HomeDir string
}
```

Choose what you want to output to the file, most likely the `Username` field or maybe the `Name` field. These are fields of `string` type, so these you can pass without a problem:

```
if _, err = f.WriteString(cur.Username); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

If you want to write out the complete `User` struct, you may use the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, conveniently the [`fmt.Fprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) or [`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) functions:

```
if _, err = fmt.Fprintf(f, "%+v", cur); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```